# Float left not working for the menu

Tags: html, css

i want to create menu bar and its contents as below but the contents are appearing on below the other :

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<div class="menuheader"> Facebook, Twitter, Youtube </div>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>  Home </ul>
    <ul> About Us 
        <li>  Establishment </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>  Careers  
        <li>  Current Openings  </li>
        <li>  Working with us  </li>
        <li> Work Culture  </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>  Contact Us  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu{
    background-color:#999999;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    width:940px;
    height:50px;
    margin:20px;
    padding:20px;
    font-size:12px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Where's your BODY tag? Also, to better work with menus, use nested lists. It's a convention for semantic markup: `<ul><li>Option 1</li><li>Option 2<ul><li>Option 2.1</li></ul></li></ul>`

Answer (score 1):

The float:left is working, however, your padding of 20px to the right is causing the problem. I made a fiddle for you, http://jsfiddle.net/tsJ7r/1/
Change:

```
  padding:20px;
```

to:

```
padding:0px;
```

and it should work
If you want the padding to be there on all sides except the left, you can use

```
padding-top:20px;
padding-bottom:20px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your unordered list markup is not correct. Try something like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Careers
       <ul>
           <li>Current Openings</li>
           <li>Working With Us</li>
           <li>Working Culture</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
```

Then your CSS would look like this:

```
ul.menu {
    float: left;
}

ul.menu li {
     float: left;
     padding: 20px;
     // etc.
}
```